# Video not playing on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, video, playback

[image]I have just got a simple video going. When I run the app in Simulator the video plays but when I run it on my iPhone it says video missing. Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerviewcontroller = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerview = AVPlayer ()

    @IBAction func playMusic(sender: AnyObject) {
        var fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/MorganEvans/Documents/Apps/32134.mp4")
        playerview = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

        playerviewcontroller.player = playerview

        self.presentViewController(playerviewcontroller, animated: true){

            self.playerviewcontroller.player?.play()
        }


    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using a video path for your machine in disk which definitely will not work in device. Try add the video in the project files and use `NSBundle` to get its path.

Comment: Please tell me how/where I add it to. Thanks

Comment: I have added how/where as answer. Please check

Answer (score 1):

The video file should be added in Xcode project like this:

[image]

Then you can get the video url like this:

```
let movieURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("ElephantSeals", withExtension: "mov")!
```

Comment: It comes up with the error - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: double check the name of your video file and extension

Comment: Yep its correct but its not in a common file. how to i find that folder`/ thanks

Comment: Common folder is just for clarification. You can create any folder with any name to combine your videos inside.

Comment: Ok please see the photo I have put on of the error. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Please put the video file into your project bundle. Simply drag and drop the video into your project.

```
NSURL *url=[[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"arreg" withExtension:@"mp4"];
AVPlayer *video=[AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
AVPlayerViewController *controller=[[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.player=video;
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

controller.view.frame=self.view.frame;
[self addChildViewController:controller];

[video play];
```